# Can an LXD client run a desktop environment?

Tags: virtualization, gui, desktop-environments, lxd, container

The examples given for LXD [[1]](https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/lxd) [[2]](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/) centre around terminal-based server use-cases. Can an LXD client run a graphical desktop environment in the same way as, for example, GNOME Boxes or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2):

From the [LXD issue tracker](https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/3202):

> Short answer is "no". Containers don't have virtual graphic cards so there's nothing for them to render to.
>
> There are some alternatives though:
>
> - Run Xephyr or similar on the host, then pass the X socket to the container and run things against that
> - Run some kind of VNC/RDP based server in the container and connect to that from the host
> - Give the container full access to your host's devices (GPU and terminal), this would let you have your desktop environment in a container with a mostly blank host

Comment: Hi, did you proceed with trying out LXD (Docker?) to run any GUI-based applications or desktop environment? I saw https://community.kde.org/Neon/Docker and remembered this question of yours!